# Chrome Notifications not appearing from Chrome Extension background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Using the new `chrome.notifications` API, I am unable to get notifications from my extension to appear. Even the most basic notification fails to appear for me, but I get no errors and the callback function is properly executed.

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "notify",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }
}
```

#### main.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var opt = {
    type: 'list',
    title: 'Primary Title',
    message: 'Primary message to display',
    priority: 1,
    items: [{ title: 'Item1', message: 'This is item 1.'},
            { title: 'Item2', message: 'This is item 2.'},
            { title: 'Item3', message: 'This is item 3.'}]
  };
  chrome.notifications.create('notify1', opt, function() { console.log('created!'); });
});
```

When I inspect the background page, I can see "created!" in the console, but I don't ever get a notification on the desktop. I have tried a bunch of different priority values to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Compare the behavior in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notifications-galore/gclcddgeeaknflkijpcbplmhbkonmlij?hl=en (see that item's description for source). Narrow down the responsible differences, then please post an answer to your own question here.

Comment: Using the exact id and options from one of the examples from the app you mentioned, I get the same results. The only difference that I can see is that I am using an Chrome Extension, and your example (and all other examples I've found) are using Chrome Apps.

Comment: Are the working examples calling the create method from the background page?

Comment: Yes, the working examples are calling the create method from the background page. As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the working examples use a Chrome App instead of an Extension.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately detailed error messages for chrome.notifications have been suppressed from the console due to a bug that I haven't yet diagnosed; the reason your notification isn't being displayed is that it doesn't provide a required "iconUrl" parameter.  When I tried the following in the background page of an extension I have installed:

```
var opt = {
  iconUrl: "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
  type: 'list',
  title: 'Primary Title',
  message: 'Primary message to display',
  priority: 1,
  items: [{ title: 'Item1', message: 'This is item 1.'},
        { title: 'Item2', message: 'This is item 2.'},
          { title: 'Item3', message: 'This is item 3.'}]
};
chrome.notifications.create('notify1', opt, function() { console.log('created!'); });
```

the notification is created successfully.  It pays to check chrome.runtime.lastError:

```
var opt = {
    type: 'list',
    title: 'Primary Title',
    message: 'Primary message to display',
    priority: 1,
    items: [{ title: 'Item1', message: 'This is item 1.'},
            { title: 'Item2', message: 'This is item 2.'},
            { title: 'Item3', message: 'This is item 3.'}]
  };
  chrome.notifications.create('notify1', opt, function(id) { console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError); });
```

which would have shown you that in fact there are required properties and one is missing.

Comment: Thanks for an awesome answer! The tip about `chrome.runtime.lastError` was also really useful.

Comment: I find it strange that the chrome API document states that the iconUrl parameter is optional. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions

Comment: They've changed it, but it is still not obvious that it is required. "Required for notifications.create method"

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Mac and Chrome 59+, it might be because the MacOS native notification is disabled for Chrome. Here's two possible solutions:

#### Solution 1

Open Chrome > Go `chrome://flags` > Search `Enable native notifications` > Change it to `Disabled` > Relaunch Chrome

#### Solution 2

Go to MacOS System Preferences > Notifications > Turn on Notifications for Banners/Alerts as shown here (likely previously it's Off)

[Notifications Setting Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvISp.png)

---

[Reference 1](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/native-mac-os-notifications)

[Reference 2](https://crankwheel.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009961499-macOS-Catalina-not-getting-desktop-notifications)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I recently upgraded from MacOS 10.14 to MacOS 10.15, then
the notification broke for my extension. It turned out that the notification for Chrome is turned off by default.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, Chrome would show notification only once for a particular name/id being passed. As a workaround, I suffixed the name with current DateTime to make it unique.

```
chrome.notifications.create(`my-notification-${Date.now()}`, {
    type: "basic",
    iconUrl: "icons/logo.png",
    title: "My Title",
    message: "My Message",
});
```

Comment: Thank you - that was my problem too.

You can also leave that name/id as an empty string, and it works also.

Comment: This is annoying though, because I have a situation where I want to react to a notification button being pressed based on the notificationId, so I don't want to have to suffix it. Does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

You may have chrome notifications blocked. A good hint this is the case is if you aren't being constantly spammed with notifications from other websites. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64524782/8723748) worked for me.

[image: enable chrome notifications]

Comment: lol.. man.. you should be on top, how can i forget it.. i checked my all code.. again and again.. tried every possible combinations, debug.. aleart last error.. nothing.. helped me to figure it out..where is the problem, but when i seen your answers it hit me .. perfect..

Comment: Just a note, this was the solution for me after trying everything else, BUT despite getting it to pop up, I never see Google Chrome in my Windows "Get notifications from these senders" list with an on/off button, I just had to have the base "Notifications" on in windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

use :
chrome.runtime.lastError - add it to the callback (see example)

pay attention:
you must have iconUrl
icon URL path if related to your manifest

```
 chrome.notifications.create(`my-notification-${Date.now()}`, {
                iconUrl: "assets/images/1.png",
                type: "basic",
                contextMessage: "contextMessage",
                message: "message",
                title: "title"
            }, function(context) {
               console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
               alert(JSON.stringify( chrome.runtime.lastError));
     
            });
```